Is conservation a particular type of invariance?
As far as I'm concerned, an invariant quantity is that which does not change under some transformation. For instance, the modulus of a vector is invariant under rotations (or, more generally, under the effect of a unitary operator). Of course, Noether's theorem relates the invariance of a magnitude with the conservation of another (for instance, when the system is invariant under rotations, angular momentum is conserved), but that is not the concern of my question. Rather, I'd like to know whether conservations is just a particular type of invariance.
If we define a conserved quantity as that which is invariant under time evolution transformations, then conservations are indeed a particular type of invariance: under time evolution (or translations in time). I find this definition to be more useful in the quantum mechanical formulation, since Ehrenfest's theorem
$$\frac{d\langle A\rangle}{dt} = \frac{i}{\hbar}[H, A]+\frac{\partial \langle A \rangle}{\partial t}$$
is almost the mathematical translation of the definition I have given: the Hamiltonian operator is the one which determines a system's time evolution, so if a given operator (transformation) $A$ commutes with $H$ (and of course, does not depend explicitly on time), then its action is invariant under time evolution, and its expectation value must be constant in time, so it's therefore a conserved quantity.
Is this definition of conserved quantity correct? If not, is there any way in which we can particularize (correctly) conservations as a given type of invariances?

This is largely an issue of semantics - conservation and invariance - there is an established use of this terms in physics, even though a non-physicist may consider them as largely synonymous. We do not speak of conservation in respect to rotations, and by invariance the Q. means invariance to transformation, although occasionally we would use invariance in the sense conservation in time, as, e.g., when talking about adiabatic invariants.

Yes, a conserved quantity is invariant under time translations, as you said.
However, this isn't the same notion of invariance that shows up in Noether's theorem. In that case, the quantity that is invariant is the action, and the transformations we are interested in are changes to the Lagrangian that keep the action invariant, without using the equations of motion.
In Hamiltonian mechanics, conserved quantities can also serve an important role as generators of various symmetries. For example, the Poisson brackets (or commutators, in quantum mechanics) of the components of angular momentum form a representation of the algebra of the rotation group, $SO(3)$.
